# Requiring all network traffic go through VPN in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vpn, local-area-network

I have a VPN service that I can can connect to through Network and Sharing Center manually and this works great, but sometimes I forget to enable it or it goes down and then my traffic is not tunneled through the VPN.  Is there a way to require that ALL traffic (other than LAN) to go through your VPN making it impossible to send packets if the VPN is down or disconnected?

I'd like to avoid tunneling LAN traffic so that I can remote onto this computer still.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do exactly what you're asking (looks like nobody does) but with VPNCheck you can make specified programs dependant on a VPN connection.  If the VPN drops, those programs you specify are stopped, it tries to restart the VPN and optionally then restarts the specified programs.  The free version of VPNCheck limits you to three such managed programs.  uTorrent should always be one of them.  :-)